# .click EVENT and the delay in TOUCH screens

Tags: jquery, performance, mobile, click, touchscreen

## Good morning people!

You have used something to make the event .click more optimized for touch screens?

I saw that it has a delay in these devices and the correct would be to use tap or touchstart.

I would like to hear from you if there is good practice for hybrid sites.

hugs

Comment: You can either use a library like fastclick.js or replace the click event in your code with the touchstart event.